# How to render leaflet map when in hidden "display: none;" parent

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, leaflet, cross-domain

I am experiencing strange behaviour when displaying leaflet map on my page. Normally the map is rendered as expected and works well. However I want to display the map only when an error occurs in forms which I detect in javascript. So if I set the parent `<div id="map">` to `display: none;` and show it later as needed, the tiles are not loaded (or only partially load and do not continue) and the map is strangely "dislocated" (not centred as defined in js).

My thought is that maybe the browser does not render the elements inside a `display: none;` parent?

I tried hiding the map with the `$(document).ready(...)` function but it made no difference. The same behaviour repeats as soon as I hide and show the map. I tested this on Firefox 44.0 and Chromium 48.0 and the behaviour is consistent.

Is this general behaviour for remotely loaded elements (ajax)?

I am unsure if this is a global behaviour for remotely loaded elements?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What's happening is that your `L.Map` instance can not correctly calculate it's dimensions because of the `display:none` CSS rule. If it doesn't get the proper dimensions it doesn't know how many tiles to load and how to lay them out, it just loads none. XHR has nothing to do with it. The map doesn't know what to XHR, that's the problem.

After you've switched from `display:none` to `display:block` call the `invalidateSize` method on your `L.Map` instance. It will force the map to (re)render:

> Checks if the map container size changed and updates the map if so — call it after you've changed the map size dynamically, also animating pan by default. If options.pan is false, panning will not occur. If options.debounceMoveend is true, it will delay moveend event so that it doesn't happen often even if the method is called many times in a row.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-invalidatesize

Answer (score 4):

Another workaround is to use `opacity: 0;` or `height: 0px;` instead of `display: none;`

Answer (score 0):

The workaround seems to be in hiding the map only after the page has been loaded like so:

```
$( window ).load(function () {
    $('#map').hide();
});
```

This way the map is hidden only after it has been completely rendered. Showing it after this with `$('#map').show();` show a map with loaded tiles that you would expect with no problems.

Comment: i don't think so. if you are not answering to your own question and if this is a part of your question please put your markup and js in your question. This area is for answers.

Comment: @Jai This is the actual solution. The problem was that at the time of writing the question I had another hidden line in code that was hiding the map before the window is loaded so I thought this does not work. Is this ok?

Comment: What you're doing now is a work-around. Not as much an actual solution. You can perfectly hide the map with `display:none` and switch to `display:block` when you need it. Check my answer.