# Two maps on the same page with Leaflet JS, second one not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, leaflet, visualization

A project I'm working on requires 2 maps on the same page.

I've differeniatiated them using unique varibales and HTML id's, yet the second map never renders properly. It has grey tiles on it. However when I put the second map in the place where the first map is, it renders without any problems.

## Map 1 JS

```js
center: [ 0E-16 , 0E-16 ], 
zoom: 1.75, 
minZoom: 1.75, 
}  
let memory_map = new L.map('memory_map', memory_mapOptions); 
let memory_cartodbAttribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>';
let memory_layer = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: memory_cartodbAttribution}).addTo(memory_map)
memory_map.addLayer(memory_layer);
let memory_popup = new L.popup();
function memory_onMapClick(e) {
   memory_popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(memory_map);
}
memory_map.on('click', memory_onMapClick);
```

[image]

## Map 2 JS

```js
                
let future_mapOptions = {
center: [ 0E-16 , 0E-16 ], 
zoom: 1.75, 
minZoom: 1.75, 
}  
let future_map = new L.map('future_map', future_mapOptions); 
let future_cartodbAttribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>';
let future_layer = new L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {attribution: future_cartodbAttribution}).addTo(future_map)
future_map.addLayer(future_layer);
let future_popup = L.popup();
function future_onMapClick(f) {
   future_popup
        .setLatLng(f.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(future_map);
}
future_map.on('click', future_onMapClick);
```

[image]

## Solutions I've Tried

1. I copied and pasted the code from the LeafletJS examples, but received the same issue of the map loading incorrectly. This example used a different map and attribution.
2. Moved the position of the JS code for LeafletJS to be directly above the map in HTML.
3. Double checked all the avriables are unique (They are).
4. Swapped the maps around to see if it was an issue with the Map 2 JS. It renderered OK when in Map 1's position on the page

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Seems to work as expected https://jsfiddle.net/54y63vjo/ That said, depending on how you load your maps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220431/how-to-render-leaflet-map-when-in-hidden-display-none-parent could help

Comment: so I have figured out what was causing the issue - it was the Bootstrap accordion which changes the how the div element is displayed. Originially the second map is in the collpased section of the accordion. When it is opened it can't render properly due to the display change. I have looked at the link you posted, but am having issues geting the `invalidateSize` method to instantiate.